# Grunt won't find any tasks

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

Im fairly new to the whole "front end workflow" stuff, and im trying to learn how to use grunt, and ive set up a task to minify my css but Grunt wont find any tasks whatsoever

this is my grunt file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        min:{
            dist:{
                src: 'public/stylesheets/*.css',
                dest: 'public/stylesheets/builds'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['min']);
}
```

minify is installed globally and in the project

ive tried running the default

```
grunt
```

and

```
grunt min
```

minify is in my package.json as

```
"minify": "~0.6.1",
```

Comment: Isn't that task called `minify`? Could you provide a link to the lib? Did you install the `grunt-uglify` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several potential issues here, all of which are likely causing the issues.

---

**Problem**: You are using [minify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/minify) which isn't a grunt plugin.

**Solutions**: `npm install` [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and/or [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) as makes sense for your needs.

---

**Problem**: You aren't loading any plugins/tasks...at least not in the code you posted.

**Solution**: *Load* tasks with `grunt.loadNpmTasks` before you *register* tasks.  For example, if you use uglify and cssmin, you would need these lines before `grunt.registerTask`:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
```

---

**Possible complete solution for this specific issue**

1) `npm install grunt-contrib-uglify`

2) `npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin`

3) Update your gruntfile to resemble this.

*You will need to edit the directories to match your project specifics...this is almost guaranteed to fail if you don't edit it first.  See the docs for grunt-contrib-uglify or -cssmin for full details on options, paths, etc...*:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      minify: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'release/css/',
        src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
        dest: 'release/css/',
        ext: '.min.css'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'cssmin']);

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm a bit of a noob to the front end stuff. Such a help! :)